# Is it possible to make android:drawableLeft fill the parent on a Button View?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-layout, button

So I've defined a simple `Button` in xml like so:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/home_button_student"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:id="@+id/home_button_student"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_emo_cool"/>
```

I have several of these in a `LinearLayout` and as expected they fill the screen, each taking up an equal amount of space, each one looking similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5qRS.jpg

The problem I'm having here is as you can see the drawable is only the same height as the text, I'd like to know if there's a way to make the drawable scale to the height of the button itself WITHOUT using a workaround like creating my own Button using another `LinearLayout`, I'd like to stick to using a `Button`.

I have different versions of the image in my res folder under the correct folders (xxhdpi, xhdpi, and so on) but it only seems to want to use the smallest one.

EDIT: It seems like this may be due to the image supplied being too small, as I said just above I have the image in a whole range of sizes, how can I tell android to use a larger one on a larger screen instead of defaulting to the smaller one? I thought that was the whole point of having multiple sizes in the first place.

Comment: Having the images in the folders marked with densities means only the correct density image will be used. Say you have an icon 48px x 48px in your `drawable-mdpi` folder. This means on `mdpi` device this image will be loaded and rendered as 48dp x 48dp because `mdpi` scale is 1. The same image in `drawable-hdpi` should be 72px x 72px because the `hdpi` scale is 1.5. It will also render as 48dp x 48dp.

Comment: Thanks, I was misunderstanding how this stuff worked. That makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawable will only be the size the bitmap is. Just provide larger image and it should be fine.

Comment: I've started to think this may be the case, however I have an image for each size in the relevant drawable folders. If this is the problem then how do I specify I'd like to use the higher resolution image instead of the smaller one?

Comment: What are the sizes of the bitmaps? Are you increasing the height of the button or is the wighting changing the width?

Comment: 96, 64, 48, 32, 24 px squares. The weight is changing the height, but to test I also tried setting a specific height myself and got the same result.

Comment: As I have commented to the original question, the loaded image will be fixed size in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to change your layout_height from fill_parent to wrap_content like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/home_button_student"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:id="@+id/home_button_student"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_emo_cool"/>
```

If you want a button real big in height, then make sure you have an equal heighted drawable image.and also there's no need to give weight here,

Comment: I need `layout_weight` and `fill_parent` though because as I explained I'd like my buttons (say for example I have 5 of them) to fill the available space scaling to equal height. This answer just sizes the button height to match the text, the drawable is still tiny. I'd like the drawable to scale to be as tall as the `Button` whose height is determined by the layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your custom layout for that like drawable left or right whatever you want just use linear layout put in this imageview and button for the view. so you can put image that you wants